# How to get the return value from EXEC(Query) inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to get the return value from the following SQL script?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spInvert 
    (@Id INT, @column CHAR(1))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ColumnValue CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @Query = 'select Top 1 ' + @column + ' from TEST5 where Id = ''' + @Id + ''

    SET @ColumnValue = EXEC(@Query) // here I need to get the column value
END
```

The `@ColumnValue` will be 1 or 0. I am expecting single value from `@ColumnValue`. I want to check if the `@ColumnValue` is NULL or not. If Not Null, I want to update a table with this `@ColumnValue`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you expecting to get only one value returned?  If so you can use OUTPUT paramater, or are you expecting to get multiple rows/columns?

Comment: You can select results from SP call to temp table:  insert into #temptable exec mysp.  Which one are you expecting and I can write up some code

Comment: what table do you want to update with this value? The same table, or a different one? Do you want this handled in the procedure or outside of it?

Comment: @scsimon same table. This is inside sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update table inside SP, you can try the following query.It is better not to use `sp` in procedure name.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_Invert 
    (@Id INT, @column VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @Query ='UPDATE TEST5 SET ' + @column +' = CASE WHEN (SELECT Top 1 ' + @column + ' FROM TEST5 where Id = ' + Convert(VARCHAR(10),@Id) + ') = 0 THEN 1
                                                    WHEN (SELECT Top 1 ' + @column + ' FROM TEST5 where Id = ' + Convert(VARCHAR(10),@Id) + ') = 1 THEN 0 END '

    EXEC(@Query); -- here I need to get the column value
END
```

Thanks

Comment: @Shaju Madheena, please give your feed back in comment section. Thanks.

Comment: @Shaju Madheena, I have updated my query, please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example code I wouldn't use dynamic sql at all. Just change up the query a little bit and use EXISTS.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spInvert (@Id INT, @column char(1))
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

select @column where exists(select * from TEST5 where Id = @Id)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `TOP 1` in your procedure, only one value will be returned. So simply place `SELECT @ColumnValue` at the end of the procedure. Though, this is really unecessary and you could just remove this:

```
SET @ColumnValue = EXEC(@Query) // here i need to get the column value
```

And replace it with:

```
EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: This answer is not applicable. I want to update the same table in the SP. Any idea to help me ?

Comment: You didn’t state that in the original question

Answer (score 0):

It works as below:

DROP TABLE If Exists #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
column1 real

)
insert into #temp exec(@sqlcmd)
select * from #temp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).